# Unable to run Ubuntu Software Center in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center

This is what I get after typing `software-center` in terminal

```
2012-06-16 22:54:17,610 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-06-16 22:54:17,617 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-06-16 22:54:18,142 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2012-06-16 22:54:18,697 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 243, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 149, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Typ „ain“ je neznámy na riadku 2 v zozname zdrojov /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-precise.list
2012-06-16 22:54:21,916 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1358, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1288, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 149, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 168, in init_view
    self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.build(desktopdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 491, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 266, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 430, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 419, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 124, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 317, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 212, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Comment: try running in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t): 'software-center' and paste the output here

Comment: are you running it from a guest session or from your user session?

Comment: From user session..

Comment: If you want to submit data to Launchpad and file a bug report on your 12.04 system, [my answer here explains how](http://askubuntu.com/a/152016/22949). (That answer does *not* explain the cause of this crash, however--it is in no way specific to the particular Software Center problem you are experiencing.)

Comment: I had the same problem removing the sources list solved the problem. Delete `lists` folder in `/var/lib/apt/`. Then it is recommended to run `sudo apt-get update` so the lists folder will be created again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with one PPA.
Typing

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu* && sudo apt-get update
```

should fix it.