# Problems with Ubuntu Software system

Tags: software-center

I have some problem with Ubuntu Software System.

Once I open it up. It closes automatically without any permittion

Can someone help me out please because I dont really get this.

When I run it through terminal this is the feedback I get from the that

```
vangjush@vangjush:~$ software-center
2013-05-06 21:41:29,532 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-05-06 21:41:29,540 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-05-06 21:41:30,052 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-05-06 21:41:30,061 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-05-06 21:41:30,061 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-05-06 21:41:30,217 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-05-06 21:41:30,555 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 257, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 149, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
2013-05-06 21:41:31,504 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 277, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 182, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1387, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1325, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 151, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 173, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 324, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 119, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 253, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 238, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 277, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'**
```

Whereas when I try to reinstall software system I get this error that stops me the installation.

```
vangjush@vangjush:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
[sudo] password for vangjush: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calligra-l10n-engb camlp4 cdparanoia coq coq-theories coqide k3b k3b-data
  k3b-i18n kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn kdevelop-l10n kdevelop-php-docs-l10n
  kdevelop-php-l10n language-pack-kde-en ledit libcoq-ocaml libflac++6 libk3b6
  libkcddb4 liblablgtk2-gnome-ocaml liblablgtk2-ocaml libncurses5-dev
  libtinfo-dev ocaml-base-nox ocaml-interp ocaml-nox
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 628 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main software-center all 5.4.1.4 [628 kB]
Fetched 628 kB in 2s (225 kB/s)          
(Reading database ... 287516 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace software-center 5.4.1.4 (using .../software-center_5.4.1.4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement software-center ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up software-center (5.4.1.4) ...
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-software-center", line 170, in <module>
    result = rebuild_database(pathname)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py", line 1109, in rebuild_database
    cache.open()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 257, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 149, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
**SystemError: E:Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)**
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try to run `software-center` in the terminal, it might give some information why the app shuts down. If you cannot solve it yourselves paste the output in your post.

Comment: @Wouter:The problem is that I dont get any output. It just closes without any notification.

Comment: thats why I suggest to run it in a terminal sometimes that will give error messages that are not shown when you just start the app normally..

Comment: @ Wouter. thank you a lot but even though I run it from the terminal still I cannot find the bug. I just posted the error on my comment.

Comment: I think the last line is the error message, I fount [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151882/unable-to-run-ubuntu-software-center-in-12-04) with the same error, have a look at that

Comment: oh there are multiple, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283401/i-cant-open-ubuntu-software-centre) suggestion makes more sense to me, just to try to reinstall the software center with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`

Comment: @ Wouter: I still get an error when I try to reinstall it. this is really confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had almost exacly the same issue. Debug output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5642460/

```
2013-05-07 22:00:43,106 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-05-07 22:00:43,106 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - DEBUG - launchpad integration error: 'cannot import name LaunchpadIntegration' ..."
Reason : Open "https://raw.github.com/Nano77/various/master/deb/gdm3setup-20130207-1.deb".
```

Fix : I tried '.. remove --purge ..' update + upgrade, reinstall with no immediate effect. **After system reboot the problem disappeared.**

When I opened the .deb again - issue reproduced.

Good luck!

Comment: Update : the 'fix' did not work twice. When started e.g "software-center --debug gedit" app starts. On click on the 'All Software' icon it crashes.

Comment: Thnx I got some feedback from http://superuser.com/questions/592257/problems-with-ubuntu-software-center/592294?noredirect=1#comment727589_592294 and it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

1) `sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center`

2) `sudo apt-get install software-center`

3) `sudo software-center &`

Comment: @ Hojat: This is the error that I get when i do the above steps.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'

Comment: it is a bug in software center, so just run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` this should fix this.

Comment: Even though I try to update it still shows an error

vangjush@vangjush:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for vangjush: 
E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: it seems that you have changed your  sources file, please send us this file..

Comment: Unfortunate the context of the file has more than 2 two links and I cannot post it on my question. Can you give me your email and I will send you by mail.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5639695/ you can find it from this link. just upload it