# Why does Compiz crash on the Ubuntu host when opening Windows 7 in Virtualbox?

Tags: compiz, virtualbox, bug-reporting

I opened a Windows 7 virtual machine tonight from VirtualBox, and compiz crashed, resulting in me thinking for about a minute that my laptop had frozen, but it came back with a compiz crash after it restarted and offered me to file a bug report. It was fine when it came back.

Apparently, I can't file a bug report because precise is out of beta. Should I panic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [reconfigure Apport to report bugs from crashes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143140/why-is-the-file-var-crash-usr-lib-empathy-empathy-chat-1000-upload-empty/152016#152016). If you're willing to [submit a good bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), that may shed light on the problem and/or get it fixed.

Compiz is your window manager. When it crashes, you don't generally lose data from any applications. So no, you needn't worry.

If you want, you can switch to Unity 2D (select Ubuntu 2D instead of Ubuntu at the login screen, by expanding the session type drop-down menu, which looks like a circle with the Ubuntu icon in it). Unity 2D uses Metacity rather than Compiz, so that will make this crash go away.

Comment: Thanks very much - I enabled the apport option to track crashes.  I just hope it gives me the option not to file every crash report (i'm a software developer as a hobby, and i've seen apport come up on my own bugs with my local copies of, for example, mono).  I don't think i have enough information about what happened to submit a good report now, though, after the fact.  IF it happens again, though i might go the manual route.  p.s. i would vote up your answer, but my reputation level won't let me yet.

Comment: @RobertWilkens Sending crash data [via Whoopsie to Daisy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie/149455#149455) contributes to the Ubuntu project. So if you don't plan to continue filing bug reports for future crashes in Ubuntu software, you might consider reverting the change you made, so that future crash data are sent for statistical analysis.

Comment: As for crashes in non-Ubuntu software, unless it's configured to use Apport, you can't report to Launchpad with it ...and I don't think data from such applications get transmitted by Whoopsie, though you might want to ask a new question about that. You may also want to ask about how to disable Apport automatically for your own applications (not provided by Ubuntu packages). In the mean time, if the Apport process is taking a long time collecting crash data for your own apps, you can always kill it with [`killall apport`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/killall.1.html).

Comment: Ok, (1) I undid the changes to apport config, decided they may have already fixed my once-only crashes in development branch which i probably can't get access too.. Will participate in next beta if i know about it.. (2) I wanted, and will if i catch it again, to ask about mono specifically causing apport to trigger on mono development version questions, but it's been a few weeks and i don't remember exactly how it hapenend.