# Exiting the file explorer in vim

Tags: vim

I know to enter the file explorer in vim( by typing :e .). I am not sure how to exit the file explorer in vim. I typed :q and it gave me a segmentation fault. What should be the correct way to exit the file explorer in vim?

Comment: [Since `q` at the `:` prompt quits `vi`, this is a bug.](http://askubuntu.com/a/158274/22949) I recommend reporting this. **(1)** [Read the bug reporting documentation for Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) **(2)** Make sure [Apport is enabled](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport). **(3)** If you're running Ubuntu 12.04, [reconfigure Apport to report bugs from crashes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143140/why-is-the-file-var-crash-usr-lib-empathy-empathy-chat-1000-upload-empty/152016#152016) (you can undo this after). **(4)** Reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:q` should work just as fine with the "file explorer" as with any other open buffers. A segmentation fault suggests there's a serious bug in the version of `vim` you are using (or it could be a kernel bug or faulty RAM).

I tried this myself, but did not get a segmentation fault.

Comment: :quit also worked... which is correct?

Comment: @lakesh `:quit` and `:q` is the exact same command. The latter is just the short version of the former. See `:help quit`

Comment: @lakesh Does the segmentation fault occur with `:q` but not `:quit`?!

Answer (score 2):

I open the file explorer in the same buffer as the file by default using [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar).

I've managed to map <kbd>Esc</kbd> to delete the file explorer buffer and return me to the file I was editing, by putting this in .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType netrw nmap <silent> <buffer> <Esc> :BD<cr>
```

`:BD` is a command supplied by the [BufKill.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147). You can just use `:bd` if you want to close the buffer normally.