# firefox crashes when I use BASH (ubuntu 12.04 lts)

Tags: 12.04, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have been having the most annoying problem: every time I open BASH when I am using firefox, it (FF) crashes. Not immediately, but when I start typing - no matter what I type - it crashes...
I have recently (today and yday) updated my system using the update manager, and I suspect it has something to do with this, but being a total beginner, I don't know how to review my latest upgrades and uninstall the ones that are responsible.
perhaps I need to check for FF updates? I don't think so  - I am using the latest (?) version 14.0.1.

Does anyone have any clue how to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting this as a question about *how* to effectively report and investigate such a bug, since actually working on bugs in generally off-topic for Ask Ubuntu (and bug reports are always off topic here).

The best thing to do is to:

1. [Learn how to search for, and how to report, bugs in Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)
2. [Make sure Apport is enabled](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport).
3. [Reconfigure Apport](https://askubuntu.com/a/152016/22949) to submit data to Launchpad for a bug report instead of submitting it for anonymous statistical analysis (since you're running 12.04).

   - You may want to undo this afterwards, if you don't want to file bug reports most of the time something crashes.
4. Reproduce the crash by running Firefox, starting a Terminal, and using it.
5. Let Apport submit crash data.

   - If Apport doesn't come up automatically, this might not really be a crash. It mgiht be some other kind of problem. (Sometimes a program quits, and it shouldn't have, but it's not a *crash*.) If that happens, you can get more information by running `firefox` from the Terminal.
6. A browser window will come up where you can submit a bug report. Clearly and thoroughly describe what is going on.

Comment: @zvi If you succeed at at reporting the bug this way, you can accept this answer and edit your question to provide the bug link. If this does not work, please comment here and/or edit your question to provide details of what happens and I'll try to give further help.