# Chromium crashing very often on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, chromium, segmentation-fault

I have changed to Chromium recently ( as it works faster than Opera that I used to use ) but I have noticed that it crashes A LOT under very, VERY random circumstances. Sometimes it can go for hours, working just fine and then it will crash few times in 15 minutes and then work fine again.

This is my debug session end ( when it crashed ) from gdb in console ( not much but still better than nothing )

```
(exe:4208): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(exe:4208): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(exe:4208): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
[Thread 0x7fffe196e700 (LWP 1182) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffd2146700 (LWP 1212)]
[Thread 0x7fffd2146700 (LWP 1212) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffe196e700 (LWP 1213)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I am using nvidia drivers and do not know if this has something to do with it because sometimes I get this message

`Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try installing Chromium, the open-source project that Chrome is built upon. (`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`)

Comment: Sorry my bad - I use chromium not chrome. Do you think that it's worth trying to change it to google's chrome ?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I have just filed this as a bug report ( <proud_of_myself> ) hopefully I will get some feedback on that soon. [This is the link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1035932) if anyone is also affected.

Comment: Please note that when reporting crash bugs in 12.04, you can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/152016/22949). (But still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser.) You may wish to re-report the bug this way so the backtrace and other crash data are included (this goes beyond  what Apport submitted, the way you ran it). If you do, mark the *old* bug a duplicate of the *new* (on Launchpad).

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is still stuck in Chromium version 20.0.1132.47 
(see: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium)
So... I just added this Chromium Stable PPA and installed the new version of Chromium browser. It is running good so far... no crash yet. Here is how to upgrade to the new version:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser