# Menu bar acting weird and critical error when resetting Unity - what's happening?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome-terminal

I've been having a weird problem with the full-screen writing app Focuswriter on Ubuntu 12.04: when I open Focuswriter everything works as it should, when i minimize and maximize it once some of the menus in the menu bar aren't working, when I minimize and maximize one more time non of the menus are working, so when i click File, Edit, Format, Tools, Settings or Help nothing happens. I've noticed that the menus in fact does open they're just invisible so when, for example, I click Help and then click a bit below I see the About screen - but I don't see the actual menu. The behavior is consistent when i repeat the actions, that is minimize/maximize twice.

At a loss what to do I tried resetting Unity. This is what happened:

```
andreas@andreas-ThinkPad-Edge:~$ unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1600004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2e000a5

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:2680): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc0009e!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
WARN  2012-09-03 21:08:11 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-09-03 21:08:11 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch type: Ingen sådan grænseflade "org.ayatana.bamf.window" på objektet ved stien /org/ayatana/bamf/window48234661
Initializing annotate options...done
Initializing blur options...done
Initializing clone options...done
Initializing colorfilter options...done
Initializing commands options...done
Initializing cube options...done
Initializing imgjpeg options...done
Initializing kdecompat options...done
Initializing mag options...done
Initializing neg options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing opacify options...done
Initializing put options...done
Initializing resizeinfo options...done
Initializing ring options...done
Initializing rotate options...done
Initializing scaleaddon options...done
Initializing screenshot options...done
Initializing shift options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing switcher options...done
Initializing thumbnail options...done
Initializing water options...done
Initializing winrules options...done
Initializing wobbly options...done
ERROR 2012-09-03 21:08:14 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
```

The process stops here - I waited 30 minutes and nothing happened.

What does the critical error mean?
Can it be related to the weird behavior of Focuswriter?
And in either case: how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried reinstalling Focuswriter and resetting all setting with: 'rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*' - the problem with Focuswriter is unchanged.

Comment: I filed a report to the guy who makes FocusWriter (https://github.com/gottcode/focuswriter/issues/84) and he can recreate the error. It doesn't happen in Unity 2D so it has to do with the programs integration within Unity 3D - and it's probably unrelated to terminal error in the question above.

Comment: The same error appears in [Cannot apply unity --reset after modifying files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181863/cannot-apply-unity-reset-after-modifying-files) - can you try the suggestion there?