# Chrome shutting down immediately on opening

Tags: google-chrome

While opening Google Chrome it immediately shutdown. It just started happening.

How can I fix this. Maybe I need to reset all settings?

Comment: Try creating a new user profile to see whether that fixes the problem.

Comment: Mitch's and kamil's advice may help you work around this problem. But this should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/152016/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset configuration, rename configuration file and try to open chrome again

```
sudo mv .config/google-chrome .config/google-chrome.bak
```