# Chromium web browser segfault hangs (crashes) my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome shutting down immediately on opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195878/chrome-shutting-down-immediately-on-opening)

I had installed Chrome browsers and after 2 days my machine hangs indefinitely, the only way to get access to my machine is restarting the machine ( which I hate, badly need expert help.

This is what I see from the logs, thought it might be helpful:

```
chromium-browse[2701]: segfault at bf44c680 ip bf44c680 sp bf95898c error 15
```

Thanks.

Comment: [kamil's advice](http://askubuntu.com/a/195887/22949) may help you work around this problem. But this should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://$SITEURL$/a/152016/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset configuration, rename configuration file and try to open chrome again

```
sudo mv .config/google-chrome .config/google-chrome.bak
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not help me solve the problem, I had the same problem this morning after working around the above solution.