# Docky often dissappears

Tags: mono, docky

I use the latest Docky for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. Sometimes it gives me this error:

[image]

I **think** it happens when I try to edit the Main Menu and use Synaptic. I'm not sure. Docky is set up to be hidden on a window doge.

Please give me a patch or a stable version of Docky. Thanks!

Comment: when you do `ps -ef | grep docky`. Do you see the process still running?

Comment: Well, sometimes it does run, but not visible or it's out of my screen (determined by **TOP** command). Other times it's not running. I'll hit your command when it happens again.

Comment: This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/152016/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest stable package of Docky is already available at `ppa:docky-core/stable`. I'd recommend the following (because, maybe the package was corrupted):

- Remove existing Docky.
- Add the stable PPA
- Update software list
- Install Docky from the PPA

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core
  sudo apt-get remove docky
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docky
  ```

Comment: Ok.... the PPA thing worked!