# slow login to the desktop and xsession errors

Tags: login

Recently the time of login to the desktop from login screen has increased by 10 times. I tried to find out the reason and found that the following errors popup in the .xsession-errors file

```
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/open-vm-tools-dkms.0.crash) main process (2472) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-panel.1000.crash) main process (2476) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_shutter.1000.crash) main process (2477) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_gnome-settings-daemon_gnome-settings-daemon.1000.crash) main process (2479) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_gnome-user-share_gnome-user-share.1000.crash) main process (2481) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_hud_hud-service.1000.crash) main process (2482) terminated with status 127
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_qt5_bin_qmlscene.1000.crash) main process (2483) terminated with status 127
```

For starters, I do not have open-vm-tools installed. I have shutter, but it runs fine. I have no idea how to fix the rest of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Run `$ sudo rm /var/crash/*` That seems to speed up the login process. Maybe `update-notifier-crash` tries to parse these files???

There are a number of other questions discussing Ubuntu error reporting:

[Getting "System program problem detected" pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade)

[Why is the file /var/crash/_usr_lib_empathy_empathy-chat.1000.upload empty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143140/why-is-the-file-var-crash-usr-lib-empathy-empathy-chat-1000-upload-empty)