# Gnome 3.6 notification area not on bottom of screen

Tags: gnome, 12.10, notification-area

About a week ago I noticed my notification area had roughly it's own height from the bottom of the screen. How can I move it back to the bottom?

[image]

Comment: This may be a bug with Gnome notifications.

Comment: Any idea where I could report this? I've looked around in launchpad, but I'm kind of new to bug reporting, so maybe I missed it...

Comment: Look here: [What tools exist to report bugs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196115/what-tools-exist-to-report-bugs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an extension I had installed called "Panel Settings". [link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/208/panel-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Main.messageTray.actor.get_parent().get_height()` at line 550 of `Panel Notification extension.js`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Salem: yes, it does provide an answer to the question. It just isn't very detailed.