# gremlin.canonical saturating my broadband

Tags: updates, 13.10, whoopsie

I am seeing consistent packet push from `gremlin.canonical` which is really saturating my connection. Little investigation on the box reveals this has something to do with `woopsie`.

I have say this has been going on for almost `3hrs` and till pushing traffic measurement of about `400kb`. Should I block this, or could this be some sort of auto updates coming through?!

Answer (score 1):

`whoopsie` is the daemon that sends error reports up to Ubuntu. Sounds like you've got something that's crashing lots behind the scenes. It would be worth investigating to see what the problem really is.

Other than that, you can disable whoopsie:

- [What is the 'whoopsie' process and how can I remove it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it)

Comment: Weird! soon as your reply came through the push is stopped. Will keep my eye on it.

Comment: I have that effect on computers.