# Apport Vs Whoopsie!

Tags: apport, whoopsie

From my readings I found that both do the same job by collecting crash reports to send it to Canonical.

- So why there is two daemon processes doing the same Job?
- If there differences between them, so what are these differences?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it

Comment: This is the not duplicate. I need to know the difference not how to remove eventhat the answer will just disable not remove.

Comment: You did not read that topic. See the answer with (now) 22 rep. It is explained more than enough there.