# Where do "report issues" go?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, bug-reporting, apport

I seem to have these messages pop up that says:

> Ubuntu has experienced an issue do you want to report it?

This seems to occur a lot especially after the system freezes up for ten minutes or longer, so where do these issues get reported and how are they resolved?

And (assuming they don't get sucked into a black hole) can I track the progress on my reported issues?

Comment: I've snipped out the rant about the problems you're having because they're not really relevant to the question (which is actually pretty decent). Hopefully you'll get an answer that quenches both parts.

Answer (score 0):

They usually end up at the [Launchpad bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net) of the associated software package, development versions. I haven't reported an issue in ages, so I don't recall what the apport program returns. I think the final stage of the bug filing is left up to you (from [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport)), so if you logged into Launchpad, you get subscribed automatically.

That was how it operated once, anyway. Now the [whoopsie daemon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker) is used in conjunction with apport to automate this. Check out [What is the 'whoopsie' process and how can I remove it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it) for more information on whoopsie. I think in recent versions, error reporting to Launchpad directly is disabled and only https://errors.ubuntu.com is used, unless it encounters a new bug (from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136684).

(If the links don't show up well-formatted, somebody please edit this. The mobile Interface isn't that good.)