# Can't find whoopsie process

Tags: 14.04, server, 32-bit, whoopsie

I have tried several `find` commands to find `whoopsie` but I can't find the process to disable it.

I know it's not already disabled because when I do `locate whoopsie` I get:

```
/usr/share/apport/whoopsie-upload-all
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/desktop_kde-config-whoopsie.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/kcm-whoopsie.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/desktop_kde-config-whoopsie.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/kcm-whoopsie.mo
```

It isn't in `/etc/default/whoopsie` and `whereis` doesn't work either.

It may have been removed from the most recent version of Ubuntu LTS?

Running Ubuntu LTS Server 14.04.1 32 bit.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it

Comment: @TomNash it's not because my `whoopsie` isn't in that location and I can't find the process. Doesn't even come up when I do `apt-get -s purge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It's gone!

`whoopsie` is definitely not installed on your system any more as I get a ton more when I do a `locate whoopsie`!

(For the low quality queue reviewers: Yep, that's it. That's all the user was asking)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)