# Keep error/crash notifications, but stop Ubuntu from “calling home”?

Tags: crash, logging, apport

Is there a way (in Ubuntu 16.x, 18.x) to disable all error reporting?

I want to **keep being notified** but **disable any and all „calling home“**.[image]

I do not want to disable being personally notified, just the "calling home part". Not sure, if [disabling 'whoopsie'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it#comment1951675_135552) might fit the bill.

Comment: what about the check box below all of that

Comment: Be aware that Ubuntu developers use these aggregated crash reports to create bug reports and prioritize which crashes get attention first. By not reporting, it's less likely that your crashes will be fixed soon. Feel free to read the actual crash report in /var/crash that would be sent - there is NO user data or Personally Identifiable Information in it.

Comment: @karel Not really. This is not about repeated pop-ups and neither is this about complete muting.

Comment: @user535733 I am [trying to find out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it#comment1951675_135552).