# CPU fan works very fast

Tags: sound, cpu, overheating

since I upgraded to 21.04, I realized the CPU fan is working with more sound and speed, even when I'm in online classes or watching a YouTube video or just I'm in Firefox.

I didn't have this problem with the earlier versions, even when temperature of the exhaust air was so high.

This mostly occur when I turn the laptop on or put in the charger but eventually there were times when it happened in normal situations.

in the first line of *top* command output there is `whoopsie-upload` with usually CPU usage in 50-100 percent. [output of *top* command](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/eunv)

[output of *sensors* command](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/iwcr)

today I get an update for *linux-firmware* and after update it seems the fan speed losses some speed but the temperature has risen.

***Edit :***

logs of `journalctl -S "2021-06-14 00:00:0" | grep whoopsie`  is more than 18000 lines [full output](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/ttaw), few lines of output:

```
Jun 14 10:08:30 Enriquette whoopsie-upload-all[1672]: ERROR: cannot load /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash: Incorrect padding
Jun 14 10:08:30 Enriquette whoopsie-upload-all[1672]: /var/crash/_usr_libexec_tracker-extract.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Jun 14 10:08:30 Enriquette whoopsie-upload-all[1672]: /var/crash/_usr_libexec_tracker-store.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Jun 14 10:08:30 Enriquette whoopsie-upload-all[1672]: /var/crash/_usr_share_code_code.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Jun 14 10:08:30 Enriquette whoopsie-upload-all[1672]: All reports processed
```

Comment: Clean the vents.

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is nothing, as I can see.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it

Comment: If you see that `whoopsie-upload` very often, some process is crashing frequently on your machine. Finding out which one that is and why that happens should be your first priority. Check the journal.

Comment: @HuHa how I can check it?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

Comment: @HuHa did you mean that disable the *error reports* ?

Comment: No, I wrote _find out what crashes and why_. Suppressing the error message is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @HuHa I stopped the whoopsie-service and removed everything in _/var/crash/_ , restart it and now whoopsie is not in _top_ output.(help from another forum), but I still hear the fan sound.

Comment: Stopping whoopsie-service just disabled the error reporting. I keep telling you: You should find out _what_ keeps crashing and _why_.

Comment: I'm not good in English, and can't understand the post you send :/ , I checked journal and wrote few lines of output for whoopsie-service, I restarted the service and now it's not in output of _top_ but the fan still works fast. someone in another forum told me do that !