# 100% CPU usage when nothing is open

Tags: hardware, cpu, process

I have a problem with my laptop, when I turn it on, it's cpu percentage will go up and the fan start to work very fast.

I tried `top` command and find that there is a process with more than 70% cpu usage named `whoopsie-upload`. I tried to kill it but it's PID change **each time** that `top` command refresh.

please help me.

**update 1 :**

I did nothing before but today tried `top` command to check if a process made the problem or not.

I have a Dell Latitude E7440 with core-i5 4310U @ 3.00GHz, 8Gb Ram.

**update 2 :**

`ls -al /var/crash/` :

```
total 44488
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Oct 19 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Sep 20 18:41 ..
-rw-------  1 root     whoopsie  1705098 Oct 17 22:23 docker-ce.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie  1641187 Oct 18 15:40 _usr_bin_do-release-upgrade.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Oct 18 15:40 _usr_bin_do-release-upgrade.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 smjt2000 whoopsie 37985649 Oct 19 14:20 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 smjt2000 whoopsie        0 Oct 19 14:20 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 smjt2000 whoopsie  4206876 Oct 17 08:02 _usr_libexec_tracker-store.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 smjt2000 whoopsie        0 Oct 17 08:02 _usr_libexec_tracker-store.1000.upload
```

`ls -al /var/log/syslog*` :

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 81586529 Oct 22 23:04 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 61490191 Oct 10 00:00 /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  1305235 Sep 15 00:00 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  2042376 Sep  8 00:00 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  6402018 Aug 30 00:00 /var/log/syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  3742230 Dec  6  2020 /var/log/syslog.6.gz
```

---

`free -h` :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.1Gi       3.1Gi       397Mi       2.5Gi       5.0Gi
Swap:         7.5Gi          0B       7.5Gi
```

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensoins` :

```
total 88
drwxrwxr-x 22 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 29 18:34 .
drwx------  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Oct 22 23:49 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Feb 22  2021 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  7 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:09 apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:09 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Dec  6  2020 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  9 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:12 cpupower@mko-sl.de
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Jun  7 10:08 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxrwxr-x  5 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 May 28 16:05 drawOnYourScreen@abakkk.framagit.org
drwxrwxr-x  2 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 18:33 drop-down-terminal@gs-extensions.zzrough.org
drwxrwxr-x  5 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 18:32 EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:09 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x  8 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Jun  8 21:13 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
drwxrwxr-x  2 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Dec 26  2020 oled_dimmer@flomerz.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:17 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxr-x  6 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 29 18:34 PersianCalendar@oxygenws.com
drwxrwxr-x  6 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:25 radio@hslbck.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:15 refresh-wifi@kgshank.net
drwxrwxr-x  2 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 May 28 15:19 transparent-top-bar@zhanghai.me
drwxrwxr-x  3 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Dec  6  2020 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  6 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 18:36 workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 smjt2000 smjt2000 4096 Sep 19 17:26 you2ber@konkor
```

**update 3 :**

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extentions/` :

```
total 72
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Feb 22  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun 16 08:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 20 23:41 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:48 drawOnYourScreen@abakkk.framagit.org
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:48 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  6 12:41 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

`top | grep gnome-shell` :

```
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247052  88908 S   1.0   3.1   0:37.26 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   0.7   3.1   0:37.28 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   1.0   3.1   0:37.31 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   0.7   3.1   0:37.33 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   0.7   3.1   0:37.35 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   1.0   3.1   0:37.38 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285688 247056  88908 S   1.3   3.1   0:37.42 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   1.0   3.1   0:37.45 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   0.7   3.1   0:37.47 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   3074 smjt2000  20   0 4285684 247056  88908 S   2.0   3.1   0:37.53 gnome-shell
```

Comment: See [What is the 'whoopsie' process...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it).  You probably have some other issue going on. Can you give us any information about your actions in the days leading up to the onset of the problem?

Comment: If you have a very old computer with a super slow cpu, you will have very poor performance. What frequency is your cpu at? If you could tell that, it would be easier to figure this out. Enter 'sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt' into a terminal window and scroll down until you see a line that has 'cpu_freq=' in it. Look at the number value after the '=' sign and that number is your cpu frequency in milliherts.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `ls -al /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @64 CPU frequency is actually not a good indicator of hardware capability or speed.  If your theory is that the OPs CPU is outdated it's better to ask the CPU model.  There are Pentium 4 CPUs from over 15 years ago that have clock frequencies that exceed current generation CPUs and those newer CPUs with lower clock frequencies drastically overperform against the 15 year old processor with a faster clock.

Comment: @heynnema Edited.

Comment: Show me `free -h` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Syslog is huge. The crash files are huge. Review /var/log/syslog and look for re-occurring errors. Has this computer been running Ubuntu for a while? When did this problem start?

Comment: @heynnema This time I turned on my Laptop, the CPU fan and it's percentage is low, but usually CPU fan work very fast and noisy.(I think the problem starts about one week ago). if You mean uptime for _Has this computer been running Ubuntu for a while?_ the most uptime of Laptop was about 3 or 4 hours since I bought the Laptop.

Comment: You have WAY too many (20+) gnome-shell extensions. You also didn't show me `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. In `terminal`, do `top`, and with no keyboard input, and no mouse movement, how much CPU% is gnome-shell taking?

Comment: Did you review /var/log/syslog and check for reoccurring errors?